# Flexform not working in TYPO3 9.5, not able to fix it myself

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x, flexform

I'm working with FCE Extensions for TYPO3, to create simple Contentelements. They are working fine in TYPO3 v8 but when I install them at TYPO3 9.5 my FlexForms are not working anymore. I'm not able to find the Problem, hopefully someone here can help me out. Maybe something changed and I didn't notice it?

As the complete extension is working and everything looks fine, there must be some kind of problem at the ext_tables.php, so I will copy mine here.

The TCA Call is workin, when I add e.g "header" to the list it's showing directly. So the pluginSignature is fine too. I also tried adding `$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist'][$pluginSignature] = 'pi_flexform';` this is also not helping me out.

```
<?php
if (!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) {
    die('Access denied.');
}

\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    $_EXTKEY,
    'Content',
    'Contactbar'
);


$pluginSignature = str_replace('_', '', $_EXTKEY) . '_content';
$TCA['tt_content']['types'][$pluginSignature]['showitem'] = '
--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.general;general, pi_flexform, 
--div--;Style, --palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.frames;frames,
--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xml:pages.tabs.access, hidden, starttime, endtime,tx_gridelements_container, tx_gridelements_columns';
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue(
        $pluginSignature, 'FILE:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Configuration/FlexForms/flexform_contactbar.xml', '*');

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig('<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Configuration/TSconfig/Content.ts">');
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile($_EXTKEY, 'Configuration/TypoScript', 'contactbar');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to fix it myself. If someone got the same error, the solution is pretty simple. Move your tt_content declarations to /Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php

So you have ext_tables like this:

```
<?php
if (!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) {
    die('Access denied.');
}

\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    $_EXTKEY,
    'Content',
    'Contactbar'
);


$pluginSignature = str_replace('_', '', $_EXTKEY) . '_content';

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig('<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Configuration/TSconfig/Content.ts">');
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile($_EXTKEY, 'Configuration/TypoScript', 'contactbar');
```

And you have tt_content.php like this:

```
<?php
$tca = [
    'types' => [
        'contactbar_content' => [
            'showitem' => '--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.general;general, pi_flexform,--div--;Style, --palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.frames;frames,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xml:pages.tabs.access, hidden, starttime, endtime,tx_gridelements_container, tx_gridelements_columns'
        ]
    ]
];
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content'] = array_replace_recursive($GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content'], $tca);

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue(
    '*',
    'FILE:EXT:contactbar/Configuration/FlexForms/flexform_contactbar.xml',
    'contactbar_content'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is, that the `$TCA` does not exist anymore... Just use `$GLOBALS['TCA']`.

(in your case `$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types'][$pluginSignature]['showitem']` instead of `$TCA['tt_content']['types'][$pluginSignature]['showitem']`)

Also make sure that you place this configuration in the file `your_extension_key/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php`